# Player Join Event is not work?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, runtime-error, bukkit

I think so it not work. Please help me to fix it.

code:

```
   @EventHandler
   public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e,Player p,String JoinMessage){
    e.setJoinMessage(null);
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("&e&l" + p + "&bJoin Server");
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(p + "join server");
    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(getConfig().getString("motd"));
    p.sendMessage("&aWelcome to Server");
```

Comment: Please describe what your problem is. It is not clear what you are asking right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove Player & String, you are only supposed to have the event in the parameters.

You already have a config file so I don't understand why you would need a string in the event's parameters. Remember your class has to implement Listener if we could see your main class that would be great so we can see that you have the right code.

Does color codes work? I'm wondering because there is no
`ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message)`

or

`ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + p + ChatColor.AQUA + "Join Server"`

Check [here](https://bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-registering-events.200289/) if you don't understand this.

Example on a fix:

```
   @EventHandler
   public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){ // Removed the extra parameters Player & String
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    e.setJoinMessage(null);
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("&e&l" + p.getDisplayName() + "&bJoin Server") //I would recommend doing 'p.getName();' instead of 'p'
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(p.getDisplayName() + "join server");
    p.sendMessage(getConfig().getString("motd")); // Removed 'e.getPlayer().sendMessage("")'
    p.sendMessage("&aWelcome to Server");
   } // Could not see a close brace here in your code
```

If this isn't your issue then please explain because most people will not understand your issue.

Comment: Use either 'p.getName()' or 'p.getDisplayName()' in the strings instead of 'p'